# Angular 7: patching value of radio button Form Control does not update UI

Tags: css, angular, radio-button

I am using a HTML template in Angular 7 that consists of a number of radio buttons, each with an associated label - this is associated with a FormGroup object.  Clicking on the label should change the state of the radio button to be selected and update the value of the associated FormControl. This works, the problem I have is setting a particular radio button to be selected when the UI loads, or using `patchValue` - the state of the formGroup is correct when the template is loaded, but the UI does not reflect that a particular radioButton has been selected.

Here's code that shows the problem:

```
  export class AppComponent  {
  frequencyMinutesOptions: number[] = [1, 2, 5, 10, 60];
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      frequencyMinutes: new FormControl(5,[])
    });
    this.myForm.patchValue({'frequencyMinutes':10})
  }
}
```

The HTML template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let frequency of frequencyMinutesOptions">
                <input id="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}" type="radio" value={{frequency}} formControlName="frequencyMinutes" /> 
      <label for="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}"> {{frequency}} </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
input {
    display: none;
}
input:checked+label {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

You may see a working demo of this here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-of2ubt

(I know that I'm supposed to embed code examples within the Stackoverflow editor but I'm not sure how to do this with Angular 7 / typescript or if its even possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a type error. In your html form, the value="10" is interpreted as the string '10'.
You have to use 
`this.myForm.patchValue({'frequencyMinutes':'10'})` or (see [value])

```
<input id="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}" type="radio" [value]="frequency" formControlName="frequencyMinutes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use formGroupName or call external function to make default radio button as true.

```
    <div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <ul>
           <li *ngFor="let frequency of frequencyMinutesOptions">
                <input id="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}" type="radio" value="{{frequency}}" formControlName="frequencyMinutes" [checked]="isDefaultSelection(frequency)" >
      <label for="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}"> {{frequency}} </label>
    </li>
</ul>
   </form>
      <div class="debug">{{myForm.value | json}}
     </div> 
  </div>


   export class AppComponent  {
      frequencyMinutesOptions: number[] = [1, 2, 5, 10, 60];
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      frequencyMinutes: new FormControl(5,[])
        });
        this.myForm.patchValue({'frequencyMinutes':10})
      }
     isDefaultSelection(frequency) {
       return frequency == 10 ? true : false;
     }
   }
```

or simply use property-binding

```
<input id="asset-frequency-{{frequency}}" type="radio" [value]="frequency" formControlName="frequencyMinutes">
```